# how to return a value from a LINQ statement

Tags: linq

```
var x = from y in db.table
            where y.member_id == 1
            select new { y.member_id };
```

this statement should return only one record. & i want to retrieve that value the statement returns in a string format.

like

```
string m = x;
```

how can i do that?!

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = (from y in db.table
         where y.member_id == 1
         select new { y.member_id }).FirstOrDefault();
```

It'll return `null` if the user didn't exist.

You'll likely want to get rid of the `new { }` part though, if `y.member_id` is supposed to be a string.

```
var x = (from y in db.table
         where y.member_id == 1
         select y.member_id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use :

```
string m = db.table.where(member=>member.member_id == 1).FirstOrDefault().member_id.ToString();
```

, provided 'table' is a POCO or it can support property access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `take 1` to limit the number of returned elements to one, but still you'll get a collection back from the query (of which you'd have to extract the first element using e.g. `.First()`).

But why not just use

```
val element = db.table.First(x => x.member_id == 1);
```

to find the element that satisfies your predicate?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the statement should only return a single result, instead of using `.First/.FirstOrDefault` you should use `.Single/.SingleOrDefault` so that you are effectively asserting that there will be only a single result. If the query returns more than one item, that would then be an error situation. This might be useful.